# Why does bootstrap datepicker displays default date as 00/14/2014?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I have a bootstrap datepicker that works fine. However, when I try to set a default date, something goes wrong. I tried two different methods, but neither works:

```
$('#cndr').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    autoclose: true
});

$('#cndr').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
$('#cndr').datepicker('update');
$('#cndr').val('');
```

My second attempt:

```
cndr.Text = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy");
```

This is the tag that contains the calendar:

```
<asp:TextBox type="text" class="form-control datepicker" ID="cndr"
    runat="server" placeholder="Elija una fecha" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- You are mixing mm/dd/yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy formats.
- In .net, `mm` is minutes.  Use `MM` for months.
- Consider that you should not be using `DateTime.Now` in a web application, as it represents time in the *server's* time zone.  Read more in [The case against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/)